# In which life cycle do I have to set data in my view pager (is a fragment) that I get from a retrofit response?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, retrofit, fragment-lifecycle

I have a view pager that is a fragment. Inside this, I have three fragments each one show a list of items that have the same model but filtered by one state (property in my model), for example like whatsapp that I have one list for all my conversations, other for conversations that I haven't read and finally other for that I've read.

The problem is that I have to refresh all the data when I'm inside the first fragment (all my conversations). So, I've tried to get all my data in the container fragment(view pager) but I cant see my first list with data(all my conversations) because when the container view is created, the first and second fragments is created too.

How can I get the data in the container (view pager) and immediately show the respective list in each child fragment?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to store data in any `Fragment`.

It is a very common use case that if a data is needed in `Fragment` (or `Activity`) X, then it will also be needed in `Fragment` Y. Sharing any state between `Fragments` is not easy and error prone, therefore I always advice to keep application's data in "application global scope".

What you need is some object, let's call it `DataRepository`, that lives in the scope of `Application` object and is injected into all `Fragments`. Since it lives in `Application` scope, the data is not tied to any specific `Fragment` and all `Fragments` can access and filter the data however you find appropriate.

The most convenient way to define such a "global" object is to use dependency injection framework (e.g. Dagger) and designate `DataRepository` as scoped injection in `ApplicationComponent`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand :D But what happen if i would like to refresh the data every time I im inside that container and is visible the first fragment... where i have to supposed to make the call to the api ? I dont know if im clear :S